# Assign the value of a python variable to a bash variable inside a python script

Tags: python, bash, pexpect

I have a python script having a variable whose value is read from a file.

What I want to do is, save this value to a bash variable so that I might be able to use it in my python script with pexpect.

This is how I want to use it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pexpect

a="value read from a file"
pexpect.run("bash_a='value of a'")
print(pexpect.run("ps -ef|grep $bash_a"))
```

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: I have not looked into `pexpect`, but I think every call of `pexpect.run` spawns a separate process. (That's what all such functions I have seen do.) So, If you _try to_ set variable in one subprocess & use in another, it will not work. Instead, set the variable in python itself. child processes (read:`bash`) will inherit it.

Comment: This was the first time I was working with 'pexpect'. I had no ideas it would spawn a separate process. Could you please explain how exactly can I achieve what I wish to? I do not understand how can I set the variable inside python itself.

Comment: @tripleee's answer does exactly what I said. That should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to put a variable in the environment, that's `os.environ`

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['bar'] = "foo"
>>> os.system("bash -c 'echo \"$bar\"'")
foo
0
```

This needs to happen before you start any subprocess which needs this variable, obviously.

Obtaining a process listing via `pexpect` seems like completely the wrong way to solve a problem, but perhaps your real scenario makes more sense.

Also, `ps -ef | grep foo` will match the process ID of the `grep foo` process.  You are much better off doing the filtering in Python.

```
for proc in subprocess.check_output(['ps', '-ef']).split('\n'):
    if 'value of a' in proc:
        print(proc)
```

Comment: You could use `pexpect.run()` instead of `subprocess.check_output()` of course, but I don't see any additional value in this isolated instance.

Comment: I cut down the actual command to `ps -ef |grep $bash_a`, just for the purpose of showing where I need to use the bash variable. The actual command was longer. Though it would make no sense to you, but just for your information, it was actually     `ps -ef | grep $pro_indentifier | grep -v grep | grep -v 'bin/sh'| grep -i prmtmapp| tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2,2`

Comment: The above command is actually returning the process id of the process whose name is stored in $pro_indentifier, if at all the process is running.

Comment: Yeah, but it's hideous.

Comment: In my defense, I did not write it.And to be honest, neither do I understand it perfectly.Since it serves exactly the purpose it is supposed to, I decided to take the easy way and implement it directly instead of converting the whole thing to a python equivalent.

Comment: This is an ancient FAQ and we don't seem to get rid of it.  The `grep -v grep` is to avoid matching `grep` itself; the `bin/sh` is to avoid matching the shell which runs this pipeline; the lack of quoting is a bug, the `tr` is superfluous (just use `awk` instead of `tr | cut`, but then you can get rid of all the `grep`s too), and there will be false positives. A proper fix would parse the output from `ps`, or invoke it with more useful options in the first place.  If you have `pidof`, by all means, and for the love of `$dmr`, use that instead of reinventing the wheel, based on a flawed square.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like adding two strings together:

```
pexpect.run("bash_a='" + a + "'")
```

Comment: But to be honest I woudn't mix two languages if it's not necessary.